# Swift and Firebase Cloud Messaging Notification only work when app is colsed

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have FCM notifications working when the app is closed but I can not get them to work correctly when the app is open and running in the foreground.

I am getting the following error  "Warning: Application delegate received call to -application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called."  I have been searching google for hours and reading the firebase documentation but I am unsure how to get past this error.

```
// [START receive_message]
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // Print message ID.
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

    // Print full message.
    print("%@", userInfo)

    ////new code to help with error but no luck
    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active {
        print("%@", userInfo)
        print("message recieved")
    }
}
```

Adding the following code did not work

```
if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active {
        print("%@", userInfo)
        print("message recieved") }
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I have not made any changes but now I can get notifications when the app is closed, but when it is open it does not crash but does not show the notification.  I can print the notification in the console.  I am thinking i need to create a local notification or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error
`Warning: Application delegate received call to -application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.` because you're not returning the **`FechedCompletionHandler`**.

You should return this completionHandler with appropriate UIBackgroundFetchResult value at appropriate place, UIBackgroundFetchResult is an enum who's values are:

- NewData
- NoData
- Failed

For Example your didReceiveRemoteNotification will becomes:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
             fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
// If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
// this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
// TODO: Handle data of notification

// Print message ID.
print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

// Print full message.
print("%@", userInfo)

////new code to help with error but no luck
if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active {
    print("%@", userInfo)
    print("message recieved")
    completionHandler(.NewData)
}
```

}

Comment: Glad to hear that, happy coding :)